Unexpected behavior with assembly ASCII validation
I am pretty new to assembly and currently trying to write a program that executes a caesar encryption with a user specified key and user specified content. The key and the content have to be a-z or A-Z and to verify that, I build a simple algorithm checking if the ASCII value is in the corresponding range. The problem is that even when given normal characters a-z or A-Z, it still returns false.
This is a minimal reproducible example of my algorithm. Even though 'a' is given to the algorithm, it still returns error. I have no idea why this is the case, I have checked the ASCII table and everything.
section .text
  global _start

_start:
cmp byte [char], 122
jg _error
cmp byte [char], 96
jg _success
cmp byte [char], 90
jg _error
cmp byte [char], 64
jg _success
jmp _error

_success:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, success
  mov rdx, len_success
  syscall
  xor rbx, rbx
  jmp _exit

_error:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 2
  mov rsi, error
  mov rdx, len_error
  syscall
  mov rbx, 1
  jmp _exit

_exit:
  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, rbx
  syscall

section _data
  char db 'a'
  error db "Error"
  len_error equ $ - error
  success db "Success"
  len_success equ $ - success

This is just an example though, the real algorithm looks like this:
_process_text_input:
  cmp byte [text_input], 10
  je _no_text_error
  xor rbx, rbx
  jmp _pti_loop
_pti_loop:
  cmp rbx, [len_text_input]
  jg _pti_end
  mov al, [text_input+rbx]
  cmp al, 97
  jl _process_capital_char
  cmp al, 122
  jg _bad_text_error
  add al, [key]
  cmp al, 122
  jg _fix_overhang
  mov byte [output+rbx], al
  inc rbx
  jmp _pti_loop
_process_capital_char:
  cmp byte [text_input+rbx], 90
  jg _bad_text_error
  cmp byte [text_input+rbx], 65
  jl _bad_text_error
  mov al, [text_input+rbx]
  add al, [key]
  cmp al, 90
  jg _fix_overhang
  mov byte [output+rbx], al
  inc rbx
  jmp _pti_loop
_fix_overhang:
  sub al, 26
  mov byte [output+rbx], al
  inc rbx
  jmp _pti_loop
_pti_end:
  ret


Check your boundary conditions again. In particular, you are failing 'a' because success condition is x > 'a', not x >= 'a'. But they ALL are one off; jg is a strict "greater" conditional, not "greater or equal". Also, you gotta use some debugger first before asking! This minimal example is golden for debugging, you could've single-stepped few times and would've seen exactly which comparison went wrong.

@AndreyTurkin this is not the problem in the algorithm, but only a mistake I made in the example. If you take a look at the code below the example, there are no off-by-one errors in there.

In the actual algorithm I can see some of the boundaries are ok, some are one off though. More importangly though, I have a feeling you got some bogus value in your index register so the loop isn't even executing. You are clearing rdi before the loop, but using rbx as the index register.

@AndreyTurkin I fixed both the off by one errors and cleared the right register but it’s still throwing the error.

@AndreyTurkin I have now updated the algorithm to the corrected version

You still have one more off-by-one check error, in the loop condition. Assuming len_text_input is the number of characters to be converted, you are trying to convert one extra character. Seriously though, debugger is your friend, you've got to learn to use it.

In the second example, what did you expect to be outputted? Also, provide your entire file.

For now, this is where I see the issue, but I'll keep on looking:
_process_text_input:
    cmp byte [text_input], 10
    je  _no_text_error
    xor rbx, rbx
    jmp _pti_loop

_pti_loop:
    cmp rbx, [len_text_input]
    jg  _pti_end ; of-by-one error -> should be `je`
    mov al, [text_input+rbx]
    cmp al, 97
    jl  _process_capital_char
    cmp al, 122
    jg  _bad_text_error
    add al, [key]
    cmp al, 122
    jg  _fix_overhang
    mov byte [output+rbx], al
    inc rbx
    jmp _pti_loop

_process_capital_char:
    cmp byte [text_input+rbx], 90
    jg  _bad_text_error
    cmp byte [text_input+rbx], 65
    jl  _bad_text_error
    ;   mov al, [text_input+rbx] -> not needed
    add al, [key]
    cmp al, 90
    jg  _fix_overhang
    mov byte [output+rbx], al
    inc rbx
    jmp _pti_loop

_fix_overhang:
    sub al, 26
    mov byte [output+rbx], al
    inc rbx
    jmp _pti_loop

_pti_end:
    ret


actually I set up the example in a wrong way, wait a second, i’m gonna fix it

The off-by-one error

_pti_loop:
  cmp rbx, [len_text_input]
  jg _pti_end


At the start of this loop where RBX is still zero and assuming that len_text_input is a non-negative number, it is not possible for RBX to be greater than a number in the range [0,maxint]. So your code will not be able to catch the empty string and in general it will process one character too many! If you'd used jge or even je it would have been fine.
The signed-vs-unsigned error

  add al, [key]
  cmp al, 122
  jg _fix_overhang


For this caesar encryption the key is in the range [0,25]. Once you have established that you're dealing with a small character a-z with ASCII in the range [97,122], you add the key. The result from this addition can go up as high as 147. Because you are using the signed conditional instruction jg where all numbers in the range [128,255] are considered negative, the greater condition might not apply and so the 'overhang' might not get fixed.
Always treat ASCII as an unsigned number
Next improved solution also removes some redundancies like reloading from [text_input + rbx] multiple times.
_process_text_input:
  cmp   byte [text_input], 10
  je    _no_text_error
  xor   rbx, rbx
  cmp   [len_text_input], rbx
  je    _pti_end

_pti_loop:
  movzx eax, byte [text_input + rbx]
  mov   edx, 'Z'
  cmp   al, 'A'
  jb    _bad_text_error
  cmp   al, 'Z'
  jbe   _add_key
  cmp   al, 'a'
  jb    _bad_text_error
  cmp   al, 'z'
  ja    _bad_text_error
  or    edx, 32               ; -> EDX = 'z'
_add_key:
  add   al, [key]             ; key = [0,25]
  cmp   al, dl                ; DL = {'Z','z'}
  jbe   _store
  sub   al, 26                ; fix overhang
_store:
  mov   [output + rbx], al
  inc   rbx
  cmp   rbx, [len_text_input]
  jb    _pti_loop

_pti_end:
  ret

